# MongoDB aggregate Query from mongodb university course

Tags: mongodb

I'm currently studying MongoDB from MongoDB University's free online courses.

Well, I'm working on part **aggregation** and tried writing aggregation query for the tutorial.

```
// This is what I wrote 

db.solarSystem.aggregate([{
  "$match": {
    "atmosphericComposition": { "$in": [/02/]},
    "meanTemperature": { $gte: -40, "$lte": 40 }
  }
}, {
  "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "name": 1,
    "hasMoons": { "$gt": ["$numberOfMoons", 0] }
  }
}], { "allowDiskUse": true})




// This is what's given as solution
db.solarSystem.aggregate([{
  "$match": {
    "atmosphericComposition": { "$in": [/O2/] },
    "meanTemperature": { $gte: -40, "$lte": 40 }
  }
}, {
  "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "name": 1,
    "hasMoons": { "$gt": ["$numberOfMoons", 0] }
  }
}], { "allowDiskUse": true});
```

Well, for me those two look identical! but the one that I wrote wont print out the solution :(

Could anyone tell me whats wrong with mine?
Thanks !

this is the sample db
mongo "mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-00-jxeqq.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-jxeqq.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-jxeqq.mongodb.net:27017/aggregations?replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0" --authenticationDatabase admin --ssl -u m121 -p aggregations --norc

Comment: There's a different between the two `0` in the regex's used in the match query.

Comment: Oh my... thanks Tom! I've literally spent hours comparing letter by letter .. didn't realize it should be O2, not 02 haha